# Click events on overlapping items

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, buttonclick

I have

- table row with click event
- button with click event, that button is on table row

and I have problem. When I hit button, row click event execute too, but I don't want this behavior. I want only button click execute, without row click.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

look at your code this is what you should do in the button click event
[stopPropagation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.stopPropagation.28.29)

Answer (score 11):

Using jQuery (due to question tag):

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(e) {
    // stop event from bubbling up to row element
    e.stopPropagation();

    // now do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call an extra function onClick

### this is the function:

```
function cancelBubble(e){

    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if(e.stopPropagation)
     e.stopPropagation();
}
```

And button's onClick you can write like

```
onclick="yourfunctionname();cancelBubble(event)"
```

yourfunctionname:: is the name of your function you are already calling.

Answer (score 1):

Also
I had a dropdown overlayed on a clickable element. So just use the following to prevent propagation to the underlying element for all modern browsers

```
onclick="yourfunctiontohandle();event.stopPropagation();"
```

For older cross browser solution, must use IE event.cancelBubble

```
onclick="if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); else event.cancelBubble=true;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since global event is deprecated, if someone wants to do with plain javascript here is the way to stop propagation

```js
document.querySelector("#outer").addEventListener('click', e => {console.log('Outer div clicked')});
document.querySelector("#inner").addEventListener('click', e => {console.log('Inner div clicked'); e.stopPropagation()});
```

```html
<div id="outer" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <div id="inner" style="background-color: black; width: 50px; height: 50px;"></div>
</div>
```

Click on the red and black squares to see the result